# Constraints needed to express a + b + c = d in zkp circuit

Tags: elliptic-curves, zero-knowledge-proofs, modular-arithmetic

I am writing an ECC based zkp circuit and need to express the constraints:

1. a + b + c = d
2. a, b, c, d >= 0

a, b, c, d will be represented by points on the curve so addition can wrap around the curve module. (Imagine d is total amount, and a, b, c are partial payments that total d)

1. is easy, it's just a + b + c = d
2. is more tricky, since I basically need to constrain that a+b+c does now wrap around the curve module.

My current solution is to use five constraints:

1. a <= a + b
2. b <= a + b
3. c <= d
4. a + b <= d
5. a + b + c = d

Is this correct? And could it be done with less than five constraints?

---

EDIT

A better solution with only three constraints:

1. c <= d
2. b <= d - c
3. a = d - c - b

courtesy of https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4887804/1305190